# Why does adding an extra dummy parameter to a function make curve fitting work?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I've been trying to do a linear fit to some data with scipy, and I was finding that the fit was nowhere near the data. To investigate further, I tried fitting a line to some data that exactly fit on a line, with the code below, but it still didn't work, as show in the plot.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def func(a,x):
    return a*(x+1)


x = np.arange(-5,6)
y = func(1,x)

popt,pcov = curve_fit(func,x,y,p0=[1])

plt.plot(x,y,'x')
plt.plot(x,func(*popt,x),'--')
plt.show()
```

[image: bad linear fit]

After seeing this fail, I tried redefining the function to have an addition parameter that did nothing, and, to my surprise, found that it worked.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def func(a,b,x):
    return a*(x+1)


x = np.arange(-5,6)
y = func(1,0,x)

popt,pcov = curve_fit(func,x,y,p0=[1,0])

plt.plot(x,y,'x')
plt.plot(x,func(*popt,x),'--')
plt.show()
```

[image: good linear fit]

Why does redefining the function in this way, which seems like it should make no difference, apparently fix the problem here?

---

Note, after playing around with this a little more, I found that this only seems work when the initial guess `p0` is already set to the correct value, although the fit with the dummy parameter is still closer to the correct fit than the other one.
Also, while I used a linear function here, this behaviour seems to arise with other types of functions as well.

Comment: You're plotting the wrong thing.  It's `func(x, *popt)`, not `func(*popt, x)`.  You'll see you get better results that way.

Comment: @FrankYellin `x` is the second parameter in the definition of `func`, so why should it come first in `func(x, *popt)`?

Comment: Sorry.  You may be calling the function incorrectly, too.  The documentation for this function says:  "Optimal values for the parameters so that the sum of the squared error of f(xdata, *popt) - ydata is minimized".  I was just quoting that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user [Frank Yellin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6457407/frank-yellin) said in his comment, you are defining your function in a way that is incompatible with `curve_fit`.

From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html), `curve_fit`:

> Assumes `ydata = f(xdata, *params) + eps`

If you define `func` with the correct order of arguments, you'll get:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def func(x, a):
    return a*(x+1)


x = np.arange(-5,6)
y = func(x, 1)

popt,pcov = curve_fit(func,x,y,p0=[1])

plt.plot(x,y,'x')
plt.plot(x,func(x, *popt),'--')
plt.show()
```

[image]

The reason why some of your attempts above have worked is that the specific function you are using for fitting is *almost* symmetric with respect to the parameters, meaning that `a*(x+1)` will make sense if `a` contains your data and `x` your parameters.